# Issues with MySQL restart on running through a crontab scheduler

Tags: mysql, shell, ubuntu, cron

I have written a shell script which starts MySQL when its killed/terminated. I am running this shell script using a crontab.

My cron looks for the script file named *mysql.sh*  under */root/mysql.sh*

```
sh /root/mysql.sh
```

**mysql.sh:**

```
cd /root/validate-mysql-status
sh /root/validate-mysql-status/validate-mysql-status.sh
```

**validate-mysql-status.sh:**

```
# mysql root/admin username
MUSER="xxxx"
# mysql admin/root password
MPASS="xxxxxx"
# mysql server hostname
MHOST="localhost"
MSTART="/etc/init.d/mysql start"
# path mysqladmin
MADMIN="$(which mysqladmin)"

# see if MySQL server is alive or not
# 2&1 could be better but i would like to keep it simple
$MADMIN -h $MHOST -u $MUSER -p${MPASS} ping 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    # MySQL's status log file
    MYSQL_STATUS_LOG=/root/validate-mysql-status/mysql-status.log

    # If log file not exist, create a new file
    if [ ! -f $MYSQL_STATUS_LOG ]; then
        cat "Creating MySQL status log file.." > $MYSQL_STATUS_LOG
        now="$(date)"
        echo [$now] error     : MySQL not running >> $MYSQL_STATUS_LOG
    else
        now="$(date)"
        echo [$now] error     : MySQL not running >> $MYSQL_STATUS_LOG
    fi

    # Restarting MySQL
    /etc/init.d/mysql start

    now1="$(date)"
    echo [$now1] info     : MySQL started >> $MYSQL_STATUS_LOG
    cat $MYSQL_STATUS_LOG
fi
```

When I run the above **mysql shell script manually using webmin's crontab, MySQL started successfully** (when its killed).

However, **when I schedule it using a cron job, MySQL doesn't starts.** *The logs are printed properly* (it means my cron runs the scheduled script successfully, however MySQL is not restarting).

*crontab -l* displays:

```
* * * * * sh /root/mysql.sh
```

I found from URL's that we should give absolute path to restart MySQL through schedulers like cron. However, it haven't worked for me.

Can anyone please help me!

Thank You.

Comment: What's your cronjob line? Note you may need to give full paths to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have given full path in 'mysql.sh' file which  my cron use. Also, sorry I am not sure about 'cronjob line'. can you please say, how to get the value of it?

Comment: Yes I mean the line you added when doing `crontab -e`. It may be something like `* * * * * /bin/sh /path/to/your/script.sh`

Comment: Thank you. It displays, * * * * * sh /root/mysql.sh

Comment: OK I would try to change it to `/bin/sh` (or whatever comes from `which sh`). Also, try to give full paths in all the binaries you are using. Finally, does the user executing the crontab have permissions to execute the file?

Comment: Yes, I am executing this cron using root user. Already I have several cron jobs through which which this user (user-root) runs. Also, I tried with /bin/sh and gave full path in binaries, however no luck

Comment: Mmmm curious. Just in case, I would change the `echo [$now1] info     : MySQL started ` for `echo "[$now1] info     : MySQL started"`. What if you `touch` a file in this script? Just to see where the script gets stucked.

Comment: Extremely sorry. On close debugging, I found that my cron runs the script properly as scheduled (logs are displayed in logger). My problem is: during manual cron run, MySQL starts... However, MySQL is not starting via crontab scheduler...

Comment: No problem, one problem less :) What about `/etc/init.d/mysql restart` instead of `start`?

Comment: /etc/init.d/mysql restart doesn't works! I have also tried with service mysql start, it failed to start (in crontab scheduler). Thanks again for your quick response!

Comment: Well then I see it is a problem with the MySQL starting. As it is not my field of expertise I just wish someone comes with new ideas...

Comment: Its ok fedorqui. Thanks again for your quick responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, crontab normaly looks like this:

```
* * * * * /root/mysql.sh
```

So remove the surplus `sh` and put it at the beginning of the script - `#!/bin/bash` I suppose (why are you referring to `sh` instead of `bash`?) and don't forget to have an execute permission on the file (`chmod +x /root/mysql.sh`)

Second, running scripts within crontab is tricky, because the environment is different! You have to set it manually. We start with PATH: go to console and do `echo $PATH`, and then copy-paste the result into `export PATH=<your path>` to your cron script:

**mysql.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=.:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/games:./:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
{
cd /root/validate-mysql-status
/root/validate-mysql-status/validate-mysql-status.sh
} >> OUT 2>> ERR
```

Note that I also redirected all the output to files so that you don't receive emails from cron.

Problem is how to know which other variables (besides `PATH`) matter. Try to go through `set | less` and try to figure out which variables might be important to set in the cron script too. **If there are any MYSQL related variables, you must set them!** You may also examine the cron script environment by putting `set > cron.env` to the cron script and then diff-ing it against console environment to look for significant differences.